# Dump failed because assets could not be loaded

Tags: linux, bash, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to create alias on my .bashrc Ubuntu 18.04 to build and install APK, but I encounter problem in my terminal like this one

```
W/asset   (22684): Asset path ./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
ERROR: dump failed because assets could not be loaded
```

this is the alias I wrote on my .bashrc file

```
## install apk to device
alias apkinstall="adb devices | tail -n +2 | cut -sf 1 | xargs -I X adb -s X install -r $1"

## build and install apk
alias buildAndInstallApk="./gradlew assembleDebug && apkinstall ./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk"

## launch apk
alias launchDebugApk="adb shell monkey -p `aapt dump badging ./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk | grep -e 'package: name' | cut -d \' -f 2` 1"

## build+install+launch apk
alias buildInstallLaunchDebugApk="buildAndInstallApk && launchDebugApk"
```

it seems whenever I open terminal it will show those error because I am not open terminal from android project directory where those path belong to.

any idea how to solve this issue? can we check if those path exist from .bashrc?

many thanks!

Comment: This looks like a [tag:gradle] error, not a [tag:bash] error.

Comment: ouch, just knew it @tripleee, I will change the tag, thanks mate!

Comment: Actually on closer inspection you do seem to be asking about Bash. I added back the tag.

Comment: The alias definition by itself should not cause the code within the alias to run. Do you have another line somewhere which actually runs the alias?

Comment: @tripleee, yes I have called it inside another alias, I updated my piece of bashrc file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily check that a path exists as part of the alias or function definition.

For convenience, I have converted your alias to a shell function.

```
## build and install apk
buildAndInstallApk () {
    local p=app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
    if [ -d "$p" ]; then
        ./gradlew assembleDebug &&
        apkinstall "$p"
    else
        echo "No $p here" >&2
    fi
}
```

As an aside, your `launchDebugApk` definition contains a backtick expression which gets evaluated when the alias is defined, not when you want to use the alias.  Use single quotes around the alias instead, or convert that too into a function (and probably upgrade to the `$(current millenium syntax)` instead of `` `long since obsolescent backticks` ``); but this still does not explain why you get the error.

Broadly speaking, I recommend functions over aliases basically always.  The syntax is much more versatile, and you avoid all kinds of unpleasant surprises.

Comment: OMG, you're right, the backticks caused the problem. thanks a lot mate!

Comment: Those are backticks, not single quotes. In many fonts, they lean in different directions.